# How to do multiple typecast overloading in class

Tags: c++

How does typecast overloading work exactly?
In the following example there are two typecast overloading in class `test`.
In visual studio 2008 it always calls the `int` version, but  in absence of `int` it calls `char` version. How does it decide which one to call?

And is it even recommended to have such ambiguous overloading in same class?

```
class test
{
public:
    int a;
    test():a(2){}
    operator char()
    {
        return 'c';
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return 2;
    }

};
int main()
{
    test obj;
    cout<<obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fyi g++ 5.1.0 `error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'...` (it offered 16 possible candidates). Suggest you update your compiler, MSVC 2017 is available and free for personal and limited commercial use.

Comment: @RichardCritten VS2017 still prefer the `int` version. I am not sure if VC is wrong or it is undefined behavior (for the case with streams) as compilers might have some variations is available overloads. From source code, `operator << (int)` is a member function while for characters, it is a free function. In any case, it is always a good idea to be explicit in those cases as it lead to fragile code.

Comment: @Phil1970  you are spot on, have now checked both compilers: MSVC has one as a member and the other as free-standing, g++ has both as free-standing.  If I remember correctly the name-hiding rules come into play and as the member function is found 1st (even though it is not a perfect match) other scopes are not considered.  Whether this is a bug or not I am not sure - I think the OP needs to add the `language-lawyer` tag to this post to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually if you provide multiple implicit conversion operator, then you should be explicit about the conversion if the target function have multiple overloads. In some cases, you might want to make some conversions `explicit`.

In most cases, I would say that the best solution would be do use a temporary variable in such cases. For example:

```
char c = test; // or even better  char c { test };
cout << c;
```

The main advantage of this over casts is that you ensure that the desired conversion is available.

I have done a few tests with conversion operators and I think that VC would sometime use a conversion operator that should not be allowed. For example,

```
char c { test };
```

would compile with VC even if I remove the conversion to char operator. I think it should give a narrowing conversion error instead. It does works in trivial cases like

```
int x = 345;
char c { x }; // An error as expected
```

You could also use `static_cast` for your conversion if you prefer.

Comment: You should rarely have to do such things otherwise it would be better to have functions like `int ToInt() const` in your class.